# how to proceed delphi 7 compilation without pas

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dcu

I have project where is missing 1 pas file. But I have this file .dcu

It is possible to use 1 .dcu and other .pas files to compilation of new version?

Comment: Yes, if the `.dcu` was made with Delphi 7.

Comment: If the dcu depends on any units that you have source for, you won't be able to modify the interface section of those used units.

Comment: Not just Delphi 7, but the exact precise same compiler version / build. Even just one build number off on the compiler version could be catastrophic.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, @Jerry. The DCU format is intended to be stable within releases of a single major version.

Comment: @Rob Indeed, perhaps I was a bit mis-leading. What can happen though is, for example, the DCU may have been compiled for a later release of D7 which had a slightly different interface in the RTL, and when trying to compile that DCU in an older version of Delphi which didn't yet have that modification, that's what I meant. Always safe to be sure everything perfectly matches.

Comment: But that's just it, @Jerry. Updates to Delphi do not change the interface of a unit precisely *because* it would break existing DCUs. I'm not aware of Borland, CodeGear, or Embarcadero ever intentionally shipping a breaking change of that nature in a Delphi release update.

Comment: @Rob Fair enough, I'm just a better safe than sorry guy :-)